# Alert Message for unsaved changes in swings

Tags: java, swing

I have a one frame which consists different components(jtextField,jcomboBox,jspinner etc)

when ever user closing the frame i want an alert message that "you have an unsaved data" if user changes some thing and not saved.

Is there any alternative way to do this other than keeping one dirty boolean variable and updating it.

Like in jquery (i searched from web)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:not(:button,:submit),textarea,select').change(function () {
        warnMessage = "You have unsaved changes on this page!";
    });
    $('input:submit').click(function(e) {
        warnMessage = null;
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here's an outline of how to do this in Swing:

- In a listener attached to your component's model, set a `boolean` when the model is changed; e.g. in a [`DocumentListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html), set `documentChanged = true`.
- Add a [`WindowListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html); in your `windowClosing()` handler, check `documentChanged`.
- If there's a change, use a [`JOptionPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) to ask the user what to do.